# Mockito override return value on multiple calls from static class

Tags: mockito, powermock

There are two calls made to a static class for getting the object. Like below:

```
MyObject myobj1 = Mock(MyObject.class)

PowerMock(static1.class)

when(static1.method(param1,parame2,param3).thenreturn(myobj1);
myobj1.setcontent(inputstream1);

MyObject myobj2 = Mock(MyObject.class)

when(static1.method(param1,parame2,param3).thenreturn(myobj2);
myobj2.setcontent(inputstream2);
```

With above calls we notice that content set in the response of method calls is overridden by content of `inputstream2`.

How can we create multiple return objects using Mockito?

Comment: In order to be able to compile your code, I had to fix some problems in it: I had to change the call from `Mock(MyObject.class)` to   `mock(MyObject.class)`. The line `PowerMock(static1.class)` I needed to change to `PowerMock.mockStatic(static1.class)`. The `thenreturn`-method I needed to change to `thenReturn`. There are also some semicolons missing a the line endings. Would be great if you could update your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do multiple stubbings with the same parameters each one overrides the previous one. When you call

```
when(static1.method(param1, param2, param3).thenReturn(myobj2);
```

this overrides the previous stubbing of `static1.method(param1, param2, param3)` that returned `myobj1`.

In order to return a different return value on each invocation of `static1.method()` you need to chain the `thenReturn()` calls like this:

```
when(static1.method(param1, param2, param3)
    .thenReturn(myobj1)
    .thenreturn(myobj2);
```

Alternatively, you can abbreviate this to

```
when(static1.method(param1, param2, param3)
    .thenReturn(myobj1, myobj2);
```

Using either of the two ways, the first call of `static1.method()` will return `myobj1` and the second one will return `myobj2`.

As a result your code should first work with `inputstream1` and then with `inputstream2`.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. Appreciate your quick help on same.